# Can not access my router externally (from internet)

Tags: router, network-access

I have a router **Cisco 900E**. I am trying to access the router externally(from internet. Non local device). I read a lot about the issue and configured everything suggested. I enabled remote access via **http** and **https** protocols. The default port is 8080. Switched off the firewall and any filtering. I checked my router public ip-address via https://www.whatismyip.com/ . Then I tried to connect to the public ip address with the configured port: `http://94.236.167.2:8080` without success though. I called my Internet Service Provider(ISP) to ask if they block/filter some ports, the answer was NO. I am running out of ideas, what could be the problem?

Is it possible that my router is not assigned public IP but some local instead? Are there any cases where one can not access the router/home-based-server externally due to the ISP configurations? Could my router be connected to another router and obtain only local IP address?

Here is some additional information with regards to the router settings:

enter image description here

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

And this is what I get from my pc(LAN) attached to the router trough Ethernet cable

[image]

Comment: You need to edit your question to include the router configuration. You should also include the interface status, e.g. `show ip interfaces`. We cannot simply guess what is happening.

Comment: I can ping that address. Your configuration may be wrong.

Comment: Is this router being used on a residential network?

Comment: Not sure! How could I know that? It is not part of university campus, nor it is provided by company or other institution. I am a private customer and this is a home network

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ISP is assigning a private IPv4 address (`10.20.4.136`) to the router. This is typically only used for residential networks (off-topic here). The RIRs have run out of IPv4 addresses to assign to ISPs, so the ISPs are turning to NAT assignments for their residential customers, saving their pools of public IPv4 addresses for business customers.

The use of ISP NAT, also called CGN (Carrier-Grade NAT), will prevent you from being able to forward ports since that will need to be done on the device doing the NAT, which will be the ISP router doing the NAT. Residential ISP agreements have a clause that prohibits servers to the Internet, so the ISP does not care that this prevents you from being able to run a server on the network.

You will not have access to the ISP router that is running the NAT, so you cannot change it to forward the port. If you want to do that, you will need to get a business Internet connection from the ISP.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Some workaround? Dynamic DNS, some cloud system that keeps connection with my router/server alive or whatever?

Comment: All you can really do is use a tunnel, like a VPN. You will either need to originate it from the network, or you will need to have an external tunnel server to which the server connects.

Comment: Is it possible to speak to ISP and ask to dedicate port (forward) for my router. Then I could access it externaly

Comment: You could try, but what if other customers want the same port forwarded? Also, you will be admitting to the ISP that you are violating your terms of service, which may not be a good move.

Comment: But to connect to my VPN server externally,I still need IP...?

Comment: This is like a pain in the ass. I am browsing 24/7 and this is what just came across. Just started reading-hope it will help :). Also it could be a guide to others : https://amoss.me/2017/05/port-forwarding-behind-a-carrier-grade-nat/

Comment: It really will not help anyone here because questions about home networking are explicitly off-topic here. This would be a question for [su].